# Rebooting an instance that is locked up

Tags: google-compute-engine

One of my instances is locked up because of a major memory leak. I want to reboot it, but the only way to do so preserving scratch disk data is to SSH into it. When doing so, no commands can be executed because of a lack of memory.

Is the only way of resolving this to delete the instance and provision another? I can't imagine that being the case, really.

I've looked through the documentation, and it states SSH is the only option, so I'm curious to hear if anyone reckons otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't support explicit reboots from the outside/API yet.

This is something that we know we need to support but I don't have a date or schedule for it yet.  If you are using persistent disk to store your data (which you probably should for anything important) you can terminate and restart the instance.